# highcharts series drawing in reverse order sometimes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

Have up to 6 series in a single chart. First 3 series are columns, last 3 are lines with markers.
No matter WHAT I do, the line charts are reversed. They ALWAYS draw in a specific order, regardless if I .reverse() their data series or not.
Attached is the code that I am using. Why would columns be ok, but lines reversed? I am using angular.copy() for all the arrays beforehand to isolate it.
The idea is to have the target's actual values for each day, and have a marker showing the average for everybody for each day. The latter uses line charts with width of 0, and visible markers. I then offset the x values for each day to get them to line-up with the column charts.

This is really strange. The various series data are created with identical lengths.

Here is the code:

```
    var allSeries       = [];
    var allColors       = [];
    var aSeries         = null;

    if( $scope.drawAlerts( ) )
    {
        aSeries = {};
        aSeries.type = 'column';
        aSeries.name = "Alerts";
        aSeries.data = alertSeries;
        allSeries.push( angular.copy( aSeries ) );
        allColors.push( '#ED561B' );
    }

    if( $scope.drawSubs( ) )
    {
        aSeries = {};
        aSeries.type = 'column';
        aSeries.name = "Subs";
        aSeries.data = subSeries;
        allSeries.push( angular.copy( aSeries ) );
        allColors.push( '#FFC200' );
    }

    if( $scope.drawOpps( ) )
    {
        aSeries = {};
        aSeries.type = 'column';
        aSeries.name = "Opps";
        aSeries.data = OppSeries;
        allSeries.push( angular.copy( aSeries ) );
        allColors.push( 'dodgerblue' );
    }

    if( $scope.drawAlerts( ) && $scope.drawAverage( ) )
    {
        aSeries = {};
        aSeries.type = 'line';
        aSeries.name = "Avg Alerts";
        aSeries.lineWidth = 0;
        aSeries.marker = { lineColor: 'black', lineWidth:1, fillColor: '#ED561B' };
        aSeries.data = alertAvgSeries;
        allSeries.push( angular.copy( aSeries ) );
        allColors.push( '#ED561B' );
    }

    if( $scope.drawSubAlerts( ) && $scope.drawAverage( ) )
    {
        aSeries = {};
        aSeries.type = 'line';
        aSeries.name = "Avg Subs";
        aSeries.lineWidth = 0;
        aSeries.marker = { lineColor: 'black', lineWidth:1, fillColor: '#FFC200' };
        aSeries.data = subAvgSeries;
        allSeries.push( angular.copy( aSeries ) );
        allColors.push( '#FFC200' );
    }

    if( $scope.drawOpps( ) && $scope.drawAverage( ) )
    {
        aSeries = {};
        aSeries.type = 'line';
        aSeries.name = "Avg Opps";
        aSeries.lineWidth = 0;
        aSeries.marker = { lineColor: 'black', lineWidth:1, fillColor: 'dodgerblue', radius:3 };
        aSeries.data = oppsAvgSeries;
        allSeries.push( angular.copy( aSeries ) );
        allColors.push( 'dodgerblue' );
    }

    Highcharts.setOptions({ colors: allColors });

    $( '#chart-1-' + aTargetID ).highcharts({
        credits: {
            enabled:false
        },
        title: {
            text: chartTitle,
            style: {
                "font-family":'HNBold'
            }
        },
        tooltip:{
            formatter: function()
            {
                return this.series.name + ' for this date is <b>' + Highcharts.numberFormat( this.y, 2 ) + '</b>';
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: targetDates
        },
        yAxis: {
            tickInterval:2,
            allowDecimals:false,
            title: {
                text: 'Per Day'
            }
        },
        series: allSeries
    });
```

Comment: Can you place a `console.log( aSeries);` and paste the output?

Comment: Here's a JSON: [{"type":"column","name":"SubAlerts","data":[{"y":4},{"y":5},{"y":4},{"y":5},{"y":6},{"y":6},{"y":6}]},{"type":"line","name":"Team Avg SubAlerts","lineWidth":0,"marker":{"lineColor":"black","lineWidth":1,"fillColor":"#FFC200"},"data":[{"y":5.4,"x":6},{"y":5.8,"x":5},{"y":5.1,"x":4},{"y":5.3,"x":3},{"y":5.8,"x":2},{"y":5.1,"x":1},{"y":6.4,"x":0}]}]"

Comment: And can you tell me if the `data` arrays are good or reverted?

Comment: [
 {
  "type":"column",
  "name":"SubAlerts",
  "data":
   [{"y":4}, {"y":5}, {"y":4}, {"y":5}, {"y":6}, {"y":6}, {"y":6}]
 },
 {
  "type":"line",
  "name":"Team Avg SubAlerts",
  "lineWidth":0,
  "marker": {"lineColor":"black", "lineWidth":1, "fillColor":"#FFC200"},
  "data": [{"y":5.4,"x":6}, {"y":5.8,"x":5}, {"y":5.1,"x":4}, {"y":5.3,"x":3},{"y":5.8,"x":2},{"y":5.1,"x":1},{"y":6.4,"x":0}]
 }
]

Comment: These data are correct. The second series gets drawn with 6.4 first, and the first drawn with 4, first.

Comment: I look at your `data` arrays...this are expressed as `y,x` points. So it makes sense that 6.4 get first, because it represent the point (x,y)`(0,6.4)`

Comment: Hmmm. I see what you mean. I assumed that the location of the object in the array would be how it draws, not the x, but that makes sense. This fix will be "interesting"

Comment: If you need and specific order you just need to replace the x value on the series

Comment: Yeah - the problem comes from the fact that instead of just using the "y" or a series with just an array of numbers, I wanted to tweak the appearance to overlap the correct columns. In other words, I wanted the markers for "[metric] Average" to be vertically aligned with the "[metric] for-this-date" column. I did that by messing with the x value. I find it fascinating that there's no provision for offsetting a series by an arbitrary x or y amount. At least, I couldn't find any. Thanks for pointing out the obvious.

Comment: Ok, I am glad to help ;)